# Google Pub/Sub - should I stop consuming before seek?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I want to seek to a few hours back every few hours to prevent messages lost because of complicated processing logic. Should I stop consuming before seeking of subscription or it is safe to seek while consuming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

No

**Explanation**

AFAIK the **seek** operation in Google Pub/Sub allows you to rewind the subscription's cursor to a specific message or a specific point in time. So you can seek to a specific message **while** the subscription is actively consuming messages.
When you perform a seek operation, the subscription's cursor is moved to the specified message or time, and the next message that is consumed will be the one immediately following the seek position. This allows you to effectively skip over messages that you are not interested in processing.

Comment: There is no way to seek to a specific message in Google Pub/Sub. Additionally, seek is useful to move both forward and backwards in time. So it can be used to skip messages one is not interested in, but it is also useful to redeliver messages that were not properly processed the first time they were received.